# Prove the definite integration using infinite series

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

> Prove that $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin x\ln(\sin x)\:\: dx=\ln\frac{2}{e}$$

Now this is a very simple problem. We can integrate by parts, then evaluate the integral then put the limits.

---

I want to know how to do it by the infinite series method. The hint says to put $\cos x=t$ and then expand the integral into an infinite series.

I know Taylor expansions of all elementary functions but that isn't helping me here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: By applying such substitution the integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{1}\ln(1-t^2)\,dt
=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2k}}{k}$$

Comment: use $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2 =1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x) + \log\left(\sin(x)\right) ~dx$$

and using $\sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2 =1 \implies \sin(x) = \sqrt{1 - \cos(x)^2}$ .
We only take the positive root because $\sin(x)$ is positive on $0< x < \pi/2$

We can rewrite the integrand as:

$$\sqrt{1-\cos ^2(x)} \log \left(\sqrt{1-\cos ^2(x)}\right)$$

and substituting
$$t = \cos(x)$$
$$dx = -\frac{dt}{\sin(x)} = -\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$

we now have

$$\int_1^{0} \sqrt{1-t^2} \log \left(\sqrt{1-t^2}\right) ~\left(-\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right) $$

$$=\int_0^{1} \log \left(\sqrt{1-t^2}\right) ~dt = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{1} \log \left(1-t^2\right) ~dt$$

And the series expansion around $t=0$ is shown in Robert Z's comment:

$$\log \left(1-t^2\right) = -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2k}}{k}  $$

And termwise integration yields

$$-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{t^{2 k}}{k}\right) \, dt = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k (2 k+1)}$$

Using $\sum _{x=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{a x+b x^2} = \frac{H_{\frac{a}{b}}}{a}$

with $H_{\frac{a}{b}}$ being the analytic continuation of the harmonic number, we can write our sum as:

$$ -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k (2 k+1)} =  -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+ 2k^2} = -\frac{1}{2} H_{\frac{1}{2}} = -\frac{1}{2} \left(2-\log (4)\right) = -1 + \log(2)$$